# Adding type-hinting to functions that return boto3 objects?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

How do I add type-hinting to my functions that return various boto3 resources? I'd like to get automatic completion/checking on my return values in IDEs like PyCharm. Boto3 does some factory creation magic so I can't figure out how to declare the types correctly

`import boto3
ec2 = boto3.Session().resource('ec2')
a = ec2.Image('asdf')
a.__class__ # => boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Image`

But `boto3.resources.factory.ec2.Image` doesn't seem to be a class that's recognized by Python. So I can't use it for a type hint.

The [docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.ServiceResource.Image) show that the return type is `EC2.Image`. But is there a way to import that type as regular Python type?

Comment: I don't think we'll see this any time soon. Related: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1055 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49563445/type-annotation-for-boto3-resources-like-dynamodb-table

Answer (score 40):

### UPDATE 2021

As mentioned by @eega, I no longer maintain the package. I'd recommend checking out [boto3-stubs](https://pypi.org/project/boto3-stubs/). It's a much more mature version of `boto3_type_annotations`.

### Original Answer

I made a package that can help with this, [`boto3_type_annotations`](https://github.com/alliefitter/boto3_type_annotations). It's available with or without documentation as well. Example usage below. There's also a gif at my github showing it in action using PyCharm.

```
import boto3
from boto3_type_annotations.s3 import Client, ServiceResource
from boto3_type_annotations.s3.waiter import BucketExists
from boto3_type_annotations.s3.paginator import ListObjectsV2

# With type annotations

client: Client = boto3.client('s3')
client.create_bucket(Bucket='foo')  # Not only does your IDE knows the name of this method, 
                                    # it knows the type of the `Bucket` argument too!
                                    # It also, knows that `Bucket` is required, but `ACL` isn't!

# Waiters and paginators and defined also...

waiter: BucketExists = client.get_waiter('bucket_exists')
waiter.wait('foo')

paginator: ListObjectsV2 = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
response = paginator.paginate(Bucket='foo')

# Along with service resources.

resource: ServiceResource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = resource.Bucket('bar')
bucket.create()

# With type comments

client = boto3.client('s3')  # type: Client
response = client.get_object(Bucket='foo', Key='bar')


# In docstrings

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, client):
        """
        :param client: It's an S3 Client and the IDE is gonna know what it is!
        :type client: Client
        """
        self.client = client

    def bar(self):
        """
        :rtype: Client
        """
        self.client.delete_object(Bucket='foo', Key='bar')
        return self.client
```

Comment: How do we type hint for the variable bucket?

Comment: My library is dead, but I link to the active and much more robust boto3-stubs at the top of this answer. As for typing bucket, in the example here we don't need to because `resource: ServiceResource = boto3.resource('s3')` is typed. So, Intellisense knows that `resource.Bucket('bar')` returns an object of type `s3.Bucket`. This will like be slightly different with boto3-stubs, so I would check it out rather than going off of this outdated answer.

Answer (score 14):

The [boto3_type_annotations](https://github.com/alliefitter/boto3_type_annotations) mentioned by Allie Fitter is deprecated, but he links to an alternative: https://pypi.org/project/boto3-stubs/

Comment: per his bio, Allie is a "dude".  ;)

Comment: Lmao. Good looking out. After 37 years, I'm pretty used to being mistaken for a woman.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project in aws-samples, it is a thin integration layer with boto_stubs, and it has explicit type hint out of the box https://github.com/aws-samples/boto-session-manager-project/tree/main