# Can I tell pylance in VS Code to assume import of certain symbols globally for all files?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

I am working with code that Amazon's boto3 library. That library does not define any symbols normally and generates lot of the classes at runtime. As a result, it is not possible to use it for type hints.

There is a library called boto3-stubs, I found it in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54676985/607407 However this is a large codebase and there is certain inertia to adding new libraries, especially ones that do not actually do anything.

What I can do is use forward type annotations, like this:

```
def fn(versions: Iterator['ObjectVersion']):
    pass
```

This will not affect the runtime and the rest of our team is ok with these names. But it serves little purpose unless pylance can recognize that I mean `mypy_boto3_s3.service_resource.ObjectVersion`.

Is there a setting that can tell Pylance: "For every file, automatically import these modules."?

Comment: Can `user snippets` meet your needs? "File → preferences → configure user snippets"

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT Can you elaborate? How could I use snippets to get pylance to recognize these symbols?