# Boto3- Type Hint For an S3 Bucket Resource

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I have instantiated an s3 bucket using boto3 below:

```
import boto3

session = boto3.Session()
s3 = session.resource('s3')
src_bucket = s3.Bucket('input-bucket')
```

Then I created a function passing in said bucket in order to return the number of objects in it:

```
def get_total_objects(bucket):
    count = 0
    for i in bucket.objects.all():
        count = count + 1

    return count
```

My question is, I would like to add type hints here. I have tried the below like

```
from boto3.resources import base
from boto3.resources.base import ServiceResource
boto3.resources.model.s3.Bucket
```

But none of them seem to work. What is the correct type for `bucket` in `get_total_objects`?

Comment: See [Adding type-hinting to functions that return boto3 objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52087307/adding-type-hinting-to-functions-that-return-boto3-objects)

Answer (score 1):

I still cannot comment so I feel forced to ask you here.
Have you tried to get the type of the object with `type` function? This should return correct type that you could annotate it with further. Anyway to make it work with IDE you probably going to need [these stubs library](https://github.com/youtype/mypy_boto3_builder).

Comment: @Norboix the type I get back when I print is <class 'boto3.resources.factory.s3.Bucket'>, unfortunately when I try to import boto3.resources.factory.s3 Python does not recognise it. Must be something to do with the factory settings

Answer (score 1):

You can try boto.s3.transfer, like in this [example scenario using S3 Buckets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_s3_Scenario_GettingStarted_section.html) in Boto3 that includes listing items in the bucket and displaying their key. You can also download and run the entire scenario by cloning the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/python/example_code/s3/s3_basics#code-examples). It also includes some links that will take you to the [type definitions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/client/list_objects.html#) that should have what you need.

```
import io
import os
import uuid

import boto3
from boto3.s3.transfer import S3UploadFailedError
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError     
...
print("\nYour bucket contains the following objects:")
    try:
        for o in bucket.objects.all():
            print(f"\t{o.key}")
    except ClientError as err:
        print(f"Couldn't list the objects in bucket {bucket.name}.")
        print(f"\t{err.response['Error']['Code']}:{err.response['Error']['Message']}")
```